# Why are custom type identifiers not working?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to do drag and drop in swiftUI with a custom identifier type. There will be other

```
// In Dragable item view
.onDrag {
    return NSItemProvider(item: issue.key! as NSString, typeIdentifier: "com.circular.issue")
}

...
// Another view which accepts the drops:
.onDrop(of: ["com.circular.issue"], delegate: BoardDropDelegate(board: board, boardLane: boardList, lanes: $board.lanes, current: $dragging))
...
// In Delegate:
func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
    let issueProviders = info.itemProviders(for: "com.circular.issue")
    for issueProvider in issueProviders {
        issueProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "com.circular.issue") {
             (data, error) in
             if let data = data as? Data {
                 print(NSString(data: data, encoding: 4) ?? "failed")
             }
         }
    }
    return true
}
```

I'm not quite sure why the above does not work.

I have already added the Exported Type Identifier in `AppName--macOS--Info`

[image]